# Use a non-mandatory Exception to cause succeed on a junit test in java

Tags: java, exception, junit, junit4

I'm looking for a way to cause a succeed through an custom exception without expecting it all the time in junit4. Is this possible with a testrule or something, without touching every single testcase?

I know these options exist but then the exception is expected and the test fails, if no exception is thrown. I want the test to continue even if no exception is thrown and just use the exception to end the test in some special cases through aspectj.

```
@Test(TestSuccessException.class)
public void testCase() {
    ...
}
```

```
public class TestClass{
    @Rule
    public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

    @Test
    public void someTest() {
    thrown.expect(MyRuntimeException.class);

        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain why you need this? You are either attempting to do something that is considered bad practice, or are in an extremely rare edge case that (in my opinion) shouldn't be this easy to solve

Comment: @Euklios I have some old integrationtests I want to speed up without changing each testcase. Testdata creation/deletion are done via the website frontend so they are quite slow, but this way only the code needed for tests has to be maintained and not some extra database scripts(and the optimization can be deactivated). And tests share alot of similar testdata, so I simply intercept with aspectj and make database backups und restore them when needed. When I restore a backup I don't need to delete anything, so I just want to skip the testdata deletion phase by ending the test.

Comment: I see, legacy code. Could have thought of that one.
I have an Idea, but need to test it out miself.
Has been quite some time since my last interaction with Junit4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the junit4 source code looks, there isn't a way to achieve this.
The only way I found is by customizing the runner itself.

So something like this:

```java
public class CustomTestRunner extends Runner {
    private Class testClass;

    public CustomTestRunner(Class testClass) {
        super();
        this.testClass = testClass;
    }

    @Override
    public Description getDescription() {
        return Description.EMPTY;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(RunNotifier notifier) {
        // Load all methods with @Test annotation from the given class and fire the execution
        try {
            Object testObject = testClass.getConstructor().newInstance();
            for (Method method : testClass.getMethods()) {
                if (method.isAnnotationPresent(Test.class)) {
                    fire(notifier, testObject, method);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private void fire(RunNotifier notifier, Object testObject, Method method) throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        notifier.fireTestStarted(Description
                .createTestDescription(testClass, method.getName()));

        try {
            // Call the test method
            method.invoke(testObject);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            // method.invoke wraps the original exception with InvocationTargetException
            // The original exception is accessible via getCause()
            // Check if the type of the original exception is the custom "early exist" exception
            // If it doesn't match, throw the exception again; otherwise, ignore and mark the test as successful
            if (!(e.getCause() instanceof EndTestEarlyException)) {
                throw e;
            }
        }

        notifier.fireTestFinished(Description
                .createTestDescription(testClass, method.getName()));
    }
}
```

You can use this by annotating the Test class as follows:

```java
@RunWith(CustomTestRunner.class)
class MyIntegrationTest {
...
}
```

Note: Runner is the most generic Runner possible.
You could also attempt overriding a more specific runner if you already use one.

Edit:
As you are working with legacy, I intentionally tried not to use newer language features, like generics (`Class<?>`).

The solution is based on [this baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-4-custom-runners) article.

### Junit5

Last but not least:
This is probably not relevant in your particular case but might be interesting for future readers.
If you manage to upgrade to Junit5, you could handle this within an extension.

You could implement a custom extension like this:

```
public class IgnoreEndTestEarlyException implements TestExecutionExceptionHandler {
    @Override
    public void handleTestExecutionException(ExtensionContext context,
      Throwable throwable) throws Throwable {

        if (throwable instanceof EndTestEarlyException ) {
            return;
        }

        throw throwable;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
@ExtendWith(IgnoreEndTestEarlyException.class)
public class MyIntegrationTest
```

I tend to create another annotation (something like `@IntegrationTest`), put the `@ExtendsWith` on there, and use the new annotation.

It would be cleaner and easier to add multiple extensions.
You can run Junit4 and Junit5 within the same module, but you must replace all annotations within your integration test suit.
It might not be worth the effort for multiple thousand tests.

Answer (score 0):

For Junit4 I found a better solution for my usecase. Just override the runChild Method from BlockJUnit4ClassRunner and add a try catch for the EndTestEarlyException.

```
    @Override
    protected void runChild(final FrameworkMethod method, RunNotifier notifier) {
        Description description = describeChild(method);
        if (isIgnored(method)) {
            notifier.fireTestIgnored(description);
        } else {
            Statement statement = new Statement() {
                @Override
                public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
                    try {
                        methodBlock(method).evaluate();
                    } catch (EndTestEarlyException e) {
                        System.out.println("EndTestEarlyException - ignore");
                    }
                }
            };
            runLeaf(statement, description, notifier);
        }
    }
```